# How to search in multiple fields with OR statement in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

A have a string, let's say "Ab Cd"

I have documents with fields:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ... 'z'] (not all documents have all fields)

I want search only in fields 'a', 'c', 'f', 'x' but I want to return all fields in document.

Hit is successful if ANY of fields 'a', 'c', 'f', 'x' contains string beginning 'Ab' or 'Cd'.

Now I use this but it searches in ALL fields not in selected ones.

```
{'query': {'query_string': {'query': "Ab* Cd*"}}}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's possible to specify list of fields that you want to search by default as part of the query:

```
{ 
    "query": { 
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["a", "c", "f", "x"],
            "query" : "Ab* Cd*"
        } 
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can prefix every term with the name of the field:

```
{'query': {'query_string': {'query': "a:Ab* c:Ab* f:Ab* x:Ab* a:Cd* c:Cd* f:Cd* x:Cd*"}}}
```

Check [Query String Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html) page of elasticsearch Guide that describes these and other useful options.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what I was looking for. In case anyone looking for a java version of this:

```
 QueryStringQueryBuilder qsqb = new QueryStringQueryBuilder("Ab* Cd*")
          .field("a", 2)
          .field("b")
          .field("c")
          .field("f")
          .field("x");
```

You can even use the field level boosting if you want as shows for field "a" in above code.